# Issue with sending an email to only the users being deleted from the database

Tags: php, mysql, html

```
    // Show the members that are in the Database
    $query = "SELECT user_id, membership_id, user_email, first_name, last_name, approved        FROM vintage_user ORDER BY user_id ";
$result = mysql_query( $query, $mysql )
or die( mysql_error() );

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
$members = "<ul class='theApprovalList'>";
while($ev = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $row_id = $ev['user_id'];
    $first_name = $ev["first_name"];
    $last_name = $ev["last_name"];
    $email_member = $ev["user_email"];
    $membership_id = $ev["membership_id"];
    $members .= "<li><p>Members Name: ".$first_name." ".$last_name."</p></br>    <p>Member's Email: ".$email_member."</p></br><p>Membership ID: ".$membership_id."</p></li>";
    $members .= "<li><form action=".$myPage."  method=\"post\"><input class=\"event_item_box\"  id=".$row_id." type=\"checkbox\"  name=members_cbox[] value=".$row_id."></li><p  class=\"event_item_border\"><p/>";


if (sizeof($_POST['members_cbox'])) {
foreach($_POST['members_cbox'] AS $row_id ) { 
                $email_query_member = "SELECT user_email FROM `vintage_user` WHERE user_id='" .$row_id. "'";
            $the_result_member = mysql_query( $email_query_member, $mysql )
                or die( mysql_error() );
            if (mysql_num_rows($the_result_member)){
                $email_list_member = "";
                while($ev5 = mysql_fetch_array($the_result_member)){
                    $user_emails_member = $ev5["user_email"];
                    $email_list_member .= "".$user_emails_member.",";
                }
                mysql_free_result($the_result_member);
            }
        $to2 = $email_list_member;
        $from = "";
        $subject2 ="";
        $headers = "From: {$from}" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        mail($to2, $from, $subject2, $headers);
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM `vintage_user` WHERE user_id='" .$row_id. "'");
```

That is what im using right now and it sends an amount of emails based on how many users are in the list but only to the users being deleted, its a very weird bug. maybe I should use a limit or actually grab the amount of users being targeted? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Not all emails are going? it's sending too many? Only sending some? Your code is a huge mess right now, with no error checking at all. You assume the email was sent and delete the user's account unconditionally... if there was an email problem, you've now trashed the user's account info and can't resend the email.

Comment: The problem is its sending too many, lets say there is 3 people checked for deletion and 40 in the list. itll send 4 emails to each person being deleted. I assume the email is there because they couldnt be signed in/signed up without one, but you are right I should be using conditionals incase there ever was an issue. Im usually the only one that looks at my code which is why its a little messy, ill work on that. What do you suggest the issue is? But to add, it doesnt do anything if the check boxes are not checked so it wouldnt delete a user by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your problem (other than the fact this code could use a major refactor) is in the while loop:

```
while($ev5 = mysql_fetch_array($the_result_member)){
    $user_emails_member = $ev5["user_email"];
    $email_list_member .= "".$user_emails_member.","; // Problem
}
```

The `email_list_member` is being appended to for every user found in foreach loop. Try just assigning the value rather than appending it.

-- Update --

Ugh, didn't want to get into a refactor, but try this (untested):

```
if (sizeof($_POST['members_cbox'])) {

    $membersToDelete = $_POST['members_cbox'];

    // If this doesn't work
    $membersToDelete = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $membersToDelete);

    // Use this
    $membersToDelete = array_map('intval', $membersToDelete);

    $email_query_member = "SELECT user_email FROM `vintage_user` WHERE user_id IN (" . implode(',' $membersToDelete) . ")";

    $the_result_member = mysql_query( $email_query_member, $mysql ) or die( mysql_error() );

    while($ev5 = mysql_fetch_array($the_result_member)) {

        $user_emails_member = $ev5["user_email"];           

        $to2 = $user_emails_member;
        $from = "";
        $subject2 ="";
        $headers = "From: {$from}" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        mail($to2, $from, $subject2, $headers);
    }

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM `vintage_user` WHERE user_id IN (" . implode(',' $membersToDelete) . ")";
}
```

Comment: Thats sending the same amount of emails as it did before, thanks for looking at it, I know the code isnt the best. I made this kinda in a rush so it is choppy, but you suggest I rework how I did it?

Comment: Updated with a suggested refactor of your loop(s).

Comment: Wow you didnt have to rewrite my code but THANK YOU, I will test this after work. Side question, other then doing projects like this where can I learn how to write code like you, stupid college pretty much made me learn on my own.

Comment: I would suggest downloading a well known PHP API. There are many choices from which to choose. Some of which include; Symfony, Zend Framework, Code Igniter, CakePHP, and MongoDB. After you download one, extract it and start checking out the contents. Some sites have online API docs you can peruse as well; http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.introduction.html

Comment: Alright ill check them out, because lately i've just been using the PHP docs website and it helps and all but doesnt always give me the 'best way' to do something.

Comment: Agreed. However, some of the comments contain nuggets which I have found useful, but it's pretty rare.

Answer (score 0):

It is not quite clear what you want nor what you are doing, but running a  `SELECT` query per each element in `$_POST['members_cbox']` doesn't seem to be a good idea. Same happens with the `DELETE` statement.

The algorithm should be:

1. Get all members you want to delete from the database using the `where user_id in(...)` syntax
2. Send emails to each of them
3. Delete all of them using a similar syntax as before

And most important, modularize that code at least in 3 methods/functions!